# Best Practice for Displaying Bitmap Image in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

I am little bit confused with the Android's Best Practice of displaying Bitmap Images. I want to display one image in my screen. I have no clue about the image's properties (like resolution, height, width, etc..). I want the image should be displayed in any device and in any mode (Port. or Land).

This is what I am doing currently:

1. First find out the device's height and width
2. Then if setting the ImageView's height and width accordingly. My requirement is that I want to use 50% of the screen to display the image.
3. Finally using the below method to display the bitmap

   ```
   private Bitmap checkBitmapDetails(){
       Bitmap bitmap;
       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       options.inScreenDensity = 0;

       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               whichImage, options);

       // Calculate inSampleSize
       options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, PREFERRED_WIDTH,
               PREFERRED_HEIGHT);

       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               whichImage, options);
       bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, PREFERRED_WIDTH, PREFERRED_HEIGHT, true);
       return bitmap;
   }

   private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
           int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
       // Raw height and width of image
       final int height = options.outHeight;
       final int width = options.outWidth;

       int inSampleSize = 1;

       if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
           final int halfHeight = height / 2;
           final int halfWidth = width / 2;

           // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
           // keeps both
           // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
           while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                   && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
               inSampleSize *= 2;
           }
       }

       return inSampleSize;
   }
   ```

Now here if the source image is too large, I am first reducing the image and then finally calling Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale the image to my PREFERRED HEIGHT and WIDTH.

When I was reading the best practice in developer Android website, it is not good to hard code the height and width. I am not doing the hard coding, but I am manipulating the height and width programmatically. What do you think, is this the correct thing what I am doing?

I can provide different sized images for drawable-hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. But what is the size of the images for different drawable?

Please let me know what do you think is the best approach. Thanks.

Comment: What is your purpose for the image? Is it always going to be the same one? If not how many? Is it an image the app is going to download? Why only 50% of the screen? More background information on your actual use case would be helpful.

Comment: instead of scaling bitmap why not make `ImageView` compatible to all devices? You should avoid mixing design & code

Comment: For the time being, I am not downloading the image. So it means images are static. Total number of image: 5. My app will display 5 famous person's photo in 50% of the screen and below the image(in portrait mode), I will put a text view to display something about that person.

Comment: @Anirudh: How can I make ImageView compatible to all devices?

Comment: @SudiptaDeb [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)